# How We can Track incoming Emails in Salesforce using Out of Box Features!

Tags: email-tracking, emailtosalesforce, inboundemail

We are using Email to Salesforce for Sending email from a Record and its logged in Salesforce.
When the User replies to that email, I want to track it and show it in Salesforce. Any idea how I can implement it.PFB The screenshot for Outgoing email.[image]